# HTML Page changes layout after page refresh in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I am working on a webpage currently in the WordPress environment. I have a page on which I am executing a custom javascript. Everything is working fine on first page load, however, if I refresh the page it moves itself to the left quite substantially. The even weirder part is that this "offset" is somewhat random and changes between taking up 20% of the screen to up to 70%.

Script:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
  var el = document.getElementById("rev_slider_126_1");
  var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  var elemTop = rect.top;
  var elemBottom = rect.bottom;
  var header = document.getElementById("page-header");

  var isVisible = elemTop < window.innerHeight && elemBottom >= 0;
  if(isVisible) {
    header.style.display = "none";
  }
  else {
    header.style.display = "block";
  }
}, true);

window.onload = function() {
  var header = document.getElementById("page-header");
  header.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

I'm not too experienced with HTML and Javascript so I hope someone can point me in the right direction. I have tried setting different additional CSS but to no avail.

Comment: If you can share some HTML/CSS code as well we might be able to replicate the problem and provide suggestions. The JS code alone isn't enough IMO. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I feared as much, getting the multitude of css layers is not really possible